# Bypass the proxy i configured in wifi with spdy enabled on my iphone

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, spdy, pac

I configured a proxy with pac file url and enabled spdy-Reduce data usage features on my iphone.
After enable this feature all requests from my device will ignore the proxy i configured.

Could anyone tell me why?

Is there any workaround that my proxy can work in case of enabling spdy?

Comment: Thats not stacoverflow question. You could ask it on SuperUser site instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your specific configuration but in general SPDY works by tunnelling your requests over a SSL/TLS connection to the SPDY compression proxy (or compatible website) which means that your local proxy cannot intercept the connection without implementing a man-in-the-middle attack (and understanding the SPDY protocol itself).

It's good for reducing bandwidth to mobile devices but I'm not sure if it helps or hinders bandwidth in a business/school environment where a proxy server could cache much of the data.